# SBT gives java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to run simple "Hello!" example script

Tags: java, linux, scala, sbt

I'm trying my hand at Scala for the first time, and I've chosen to do so using SBT 0.13.9 on a Linux machine running a new install of Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

I've been following the instructions given on the SBT website to the letter, and I'm now trying to run the "Hello!" example script, which is as follows:

```
object Hi {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = println("Hi!")
}
```

When I try to run, I get the following output:

```
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:compileIncremental for the full output.
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) java.lang.NullPointerException
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 22 Aug 2015, 2:30:09 PM
```

Being completely new to Scala and SBT (and also relatively new to Linux) I'm sure I've just overlooked something obvious. No amount of Googling has yielded any answers so far though.

What should I check first? I'd really appreciate any advice anyone can offer.

Comment: "What should I check first?" - "run last compile:compileIncremental for the full output."

Comment: Try `sbt clean run`. Sometimes sbt has problem with increment compilation. Check `last compile:compileIncremental` command to see details

Comment: Here is a sample that compiles: https://github.com/csoma/Scala-starter

Answer (score 9):

I had the same error, on exactly the same code snippet! ie the first one in the scala sbt getting started [hello.html](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Hello.html)

My problem was resolved when i uninstalled the java 9 sdk and installed the java 8 sdk.

Doing this required that i also had to then re-install scala and sbt.

These I installed with the instructions from [HERE](https://gist.github.com/mbonaci/eb0a1981628553bdb846) but replacing the version numbers in the commands with scala-2.11.7.deb and sbt-0.13.9.deb (my dev machine being on ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: I'll have to give that a try. I got side tracked with other things and never got this working at the time. Thanks for the info!

Comment: JDK9 lies at the bottom of so many mysterious sbt errors I kind of think 0.13 should warn you you have to change JAVA_HOME

Comment: Or just do: `sudo update-alternatives --config java`
and choose Java version 8 (if installed of course).

Comment: If you don't want to change the default Java (for example, I want to have Java 10 as default, but use Java 8 for SBT), you can edit `-java-home` line in the `/etc/sbt/sbtopts` file (for example, I use `-java-home /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`).